# How can I adjust the number of figures latex will display on a page

Tags: floats

Try as I might, I can't get latex to put more than six Figures on a page. Naturally, I've tried reducing the size of each figure, still no go. Any more than six and the extras go on the next page, with enough room at the bottom of the first page (with the six figures) for text. What I would like is eight figures per page. BTW I'm fairly new at LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: If you have that many figures probably you don't want a float at all and just use \includegraphics withpiut the surrounding figure environment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The maximum number of floats on a "regular page", i.e., a page that contains both text and floats, is governed by the parameters `\topnumber`, `\bottomnumber`, and `\totalnumber`.

To achieve your objective of placing eight floats on a "regular" page, you could issue the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{8}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{8}
```

The three parameters are defined in the LaTeX "kernel"; cf. the file `latex.ltx`, starting around line 7215. Their default values are `2`, `1`, and `3`, respectively. Some document classes may modify the default values, but probably don't set them as high as `8`.

*Addendum*: The LaTeX kernel does not impose an upper bound on the number of floats permitted on a *floats-only page*.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Done!

Comment: Also interesting concerning floats: [How to influence the positioning of floats](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)