# How to prevent float before subsection?

Tags: floats, sectioning, placeins

I have the problem that alot of my floats show up before the subsection they are in.

I did read about `placeins` and `\FloatBarrier` here: [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)

**But this seem to only work for floats showing up in the next section but not for floats showing up in the last subsection.**

My academic advisor wants all floats to be in the same subsection. There is no "but it's okay as long as they are in the same section".

*I'm using `LuaTex` + `scrreprt` documentclass.*

Comment: Revolutionary idea: Just don't use the `figure` environment ;-) You can use `\captionof{figure}{your caption text}` instead of `\caption`  (requires the `caption` (sic!!!) package. It's one of the greatest misunderstandings of LaTeX users that graphics must be in `figure` environments and `tabular`s in `table` environments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In which environment should i put the `includegraphic` instead?

Comment: In no environment ;-) `\includegraphics{yourfilename}\captionof{figure}{your caption text}` (or the other way round if you prefer the caption above the figure). Neither graphics nor tabular environments require an outer floating environment. The only exception is `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, perhaps

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think inserting the figures that way prevents latex from selecting the decent figure location in view of the context.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: No, why? Letting the figure floating away from text where it is described is much more inconvenient. I find floating dreadful in most cases

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: With no environment i can't center the figures.

Comment: @Spen: See my updated comment ;-) Please have a look also in a `LaTeX` introduction manual or textbook on LaTeX itself.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sometimes, it is better to move the figure a little bit away from the line we placed in at. For example, multiple figures and tables may need to be separated by some text to keep the layout decent instead of enforcing them to be printed successively after each other.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Well, I have another opinion on this, because I using LaTeX for educational purposes and in that way floating figures and tables is confusing readers.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer in this case, you are right :)

Comment: Don't be sorry you don't have an MWE. Provide one. (If you were really sorry, you wouldn't fail to give us one, after all.) Right now, there is no way to test an idea or develop a solution for you. Otherwise, just place float barriers manually. But it would be better not to do that, of course.

Comment: You might also try increasing the number of floats allowed per page.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161754/how-can-i-adjust-the-number-of-figures-latex-will-display-on-a-page/161760?s=4|0.2868#161760

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I did go with your suggested solution and it did improve the readability alot. Since working with tex everyone here is like "don't place figures where you want... because typography... blablabla". I just wanted to do the right thing and lissend... but you are right! It does destroy the textflow of every reader... typography aside... tex does a really bad job at typography anyway.

Comment: @Spen: Well, TeX is quite good at typography, but it is a program following some rules, sometimes, one has to break those rules. I don't say that any of your `figure` environment should be removed, but some of them.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: But there should be rules that can be broken and rules that can't. For example text going over the page border... i will never understand how that sould be acceptable at all.