# What is the appropriate methodology to deal with figures in LaTeX to prevent fighting it all the time?

Tags: floats, formatting, multicolumn

I am writing a two-column paper and am trying to add images into it. I have been advised to just let LaTeX do its thing with the figures, but I find it generates large blank sections in many parts of the document. I try to move things around trying to predict where LaTeX will like things the most, but this takes hours of my time and it's infuriating.

Is there either a guideline of "always do this" to prevent this from happening or a way to tell LaTeX to shut up and let *me* format the document? I tend to hate when my tools try to think for me.

Comment: Right now, your posting comes across more as a rant than as a serious attempt to solicit information. Please consider applying some edits to counter this impression.

Comment: TeX doesn't work well with too many large pictures.  Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/107497?

Comment: @Mico what do you suggest as an edit? The problem is quite general in that I don't know how to approach designing a multi col document when lots of figures are involved.

Comment: @Teepeemm that document describes some common uses, but it doesn't have much information on how to deal with the 2 column problem. One option in a non columned document is to make the figures smaller, but in 2 column environments tex considers only the top region of the document to be valid and any figure spans the entirewidth rather than a single column. Minimpages cna be used to avoid that problem, but they introduced a bunch of formatting issues.

Comment: latex will not move images if you include them with `\includegraphics` it only moves `figure` environments, and it moves figure environments only to prevent getting large white space at page breaks.  As you have given no indication of your coding it is very hard to tell you what to change.

Comment: "any figure spans the entirewidth rather than a single column. " ?????  single column figures are the default, you need to use the `*` form to make a 2-column spanning figure. Really unless you show an example document that shows your problem it is impossible to guess why you are having issues.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/fewerfloatpages might help as well.

Comment: I would suggest not to pay attention to figure placement till the whole text is ready. Even at this point this is not the author concern, but that of the production editor. Focus on the message you want to bring. Problems with figure placement typically come when you have too many figures and too little text. Therefore, reduce the number of figures or arrange them in a table.

Comment: @Teepeemm Link is good, by I do not agree with your assessment that TeX doesn't work well with too many pictures. If TeX is not good, what is good then?

Comment: @yarchik Mostly, if you have too many figures and too little text, then nothing will work well, TeX included.  But by default, TeX will only put 3 floats on a regular page (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161760/107497), so if you're trying to do more than that, then you could easily end up fighting it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe these posts can help you along a bit:

- A: [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)
- B: [How to use the placement options [t], [h] with figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures)
- C: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

**Some general suggestions from these posts (and from me):**

1. Use options like `[h]` (here), `[b]` (bottom), `[t]` (top), `[p]` (seperate page) ... when including the figure, to tell LaTeX where it should place the figure. E.g. with `\begin{figure}[bh] ... \end{figure}` LaTeX will try to place the figure `h` and `b`. It always attempts figure placement using allowed places in the order `h`, `t`, `b`, `p`, regardless of the order specified by the user (`[hbt]` and `[bth]` do the same thing). Check [post B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures) and [post C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) and [this Overleaf Summary](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures) for details.
2. Use `!` to override internal parameters LaTeX uses for determining "good" float positions (as explained in the [Overleaf Summary](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures)). E.g. `\begin{figure}[h!] ... \end{figure}` will ignore user constraints in order to place the figure "here". If you encounter many white spaces, it can also be because you use `!` too often and you force latex to use worse placement to fulfil your request. For a good explanation of the `!` check [post B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures) and [post C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).
3. If you want to force "here" even more, use the `float` package and `\begin{figure}[H]`,  "which basically turns the floating figure into a regular non-float.", as pointed out in the top answer of [post A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)and it will place the figure precisely at the location in the LATEX code. Also check the [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf) of the `float` package, and the explanation in [post B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures) and [post C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).
4. Sometime is can help not to use floating environments (like `figure`) at all. Use `\includegraphics` directly in the text. See [post A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) for details.
5. Use `\clearpage` to force all above mentioned figures to be placed, before the text continues.
6. Use the `adjustbox` package. Check the [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf) for details.
7. Play around with `\vspace{}` to put in deliberate white spaces that might help you to achieve your desired layout.
8. Use the `minipage` environment. Check [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/how-to-use-figure-inside-a-minipage)
9. Slightly adjust the size of your figures if you notice that your figure almost fits in the spot where you want it, but it is moved because it is a bit too large. E.g. `\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{myimage.png}` or `\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{myimage.png}`
10. Use `wrapfigure` to wrap text around figures. Check the [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) and the [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) for details.

**Specifically for two-column documents:**

If your figures are two-columns wide you need to insert them with `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}` to make sure latex embeds them properly. Possibly you're running into weird placement issues because you're trying to include a two-column figure as a one-column figure. Check [this post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document) for details. Also, be aware that `figure*` doesn't support `[h]` or `[b]`.

I hope that some of these tools can help you with your fight against latex-figure-placement.

Comment: This is a pretty helpful post that addresses the main question, thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You don't give any indication why you are getting large white spaces, that is not expected. As a possible aid I provide an example document using several figures. If you can modify this and add it to your question in a form that shows the problem you are having, someone would be able to suggest changes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\section{zzzz}
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{A floating figure}
\end{figure}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Another floating figure}
\end{figure}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Yet another floating figure}
\end{figure}

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 
aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa 

\section{\raggedright A long appendix with non floating figures and no text}


\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{H figure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

This might seem counter intuitive, but I always wait to the very last minute to add the figures. I simply write everything I want to say, and at the end I include the figures. Then I adjust the text or use the tricks mentioned above to get my desired output.

This alleviates most of the pressure from fidgeting with the figures.

Comment: This is what I was going to post – (a) the more text you have for LaTeX to work with in finding optimal positions, the better, and (b) the document will change when you add subsequent text anyway, so wrangling diagram positioning when it's partway done is a waste of time.

Comment: Equivalently, of course, put the figures in as you go but don't worry about the appearance of the document until the end.

Answer (score 7):

What hasn't been mentioned so far in the responses and is not part of my longish post  [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/10109) on the float algorithm (because it wasn't written back then) is the package `fewerfloatpages` [(link to article on it)](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/indexbytopic/2e-floats/) which implements an improved algorithm that resolves most of the issues around half-empty float pages (or alternatively everything at the end of the chapter/article). In its basic form all you have to do is loading the package and for most documents that's enough without any configuration.

But as David wrote in his reply, it is not really clear why you are having trouble, e.g., if you use always `[H]` (i.e., your floats don't really float then nothing helps and you will end up with bad page breaks or column breaks if the float is too big to fit and therefore moves to the next page.