# Fit three algorithms in a single page

Tags: floats, page-breaking, algorithms

I am using the `algorithm2e` package to write algorithms. I have three algorithms that I want to put in a single page. I tried using `subfigure`s and `minipage`s but it got me no where.
Any help to get me started is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I tried with vbox and it does seem to work but thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

You may only have 2 algorithms appearing on a page because of the default settings for floats in LaTeX. If you want more floats on a page, follow the guidance listed in [How can I adjust the number of figures LaTeX will display on a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161754).

Another option is to put them all in the same float (say, a `figure`) and then use the `[H]`ere option to make the algorithms not float.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\begin{figure}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{First algorithm}
    \Input{input A}
    \Output{output A}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}
  
  \vspace{\floatsep}
  
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Second algorithm}
    \Input{input B}
    \Output{output B}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}

  \vspace{\floatsep}
  
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{Third algorithm}
    \Input{input C}
    \Output{output C}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{figure}

Here is some more later in the document.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}

\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter{algocf}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.

\begin{paracol}{3}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{First algorithm}
    \Input{input A}
    \Output{output A}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}
\switchcolumn
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Second algorithm}
    \Input{input B}
    \Output{output B}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}
\switchcolumn
  \begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Third algorithm}
    \Input{input C}
    \Output{output C}
    A statement\;
  \end{algorithm}
\end{paracol}

Here is some more later in the document.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]